# Linux vs Windows performance

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc

I'm testing some simple benchmarking calculations on Win7 and Linux Ubuntu 16 to compare the timings and being wonder, Win appears to be much faster than Linux.

Both Win and Linux x64 hosts the same machine, cpu clocking set equally. I'm using VC2010 with -O2 (maximise speed) optimization on Win and gcc5 with -O3 on Linux. The results are 2375ms for Win and 2800ms for Linux. Linux lags even using -Ofast optimization. No matter, gcc and g++ both give the same result.

My assumption to explain this behaviour is that VC and Win runtimes are extremely optimized for x86/64.

Could someone give a suggestion why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Pk 41
#define Lmz 101
#define Mmz 101
#define Nmz 101

// input data
float US[Pk][Lmz][Mmz][Nmz], VS[Pk][Lmz][Mmz][Nmz], HS[Pk][Lmz][Mmz][Nmz], QS[Pk][Lmz][Mmz][Nmz], TS[Pk][Lmz][Mmz][Nmz];
float F_X[Mmz][Nmz];
float Zmz[Nmz];

// output data
float Q[Pk][Lmz][Mmz][Nmz];

void Init() {
    int h, k, j, i;

    for (h = 0; h < Pk; h++)
        for (k = 0; k < Lmz; k++)
            for (j = 0; j < Mmz; j++)
                for (i = 0; i < Nmz; i++) {
                    US[h][k][j][i] = 1+sin((float)i*j+i-k-h);
                    VS[h][k][j][i] = 2+cos((float)3*i*h-j+h*k);
                    HS[h][k][j][i] = 3+sin((float)2*i*k+j*h);
                    QS[h][k][j][i] = 4+cos((float)i+j+k+h+10);
                    TS[h][k][j][i] = 5+sin((float)(j+i)*k-h);
                }

    for (j = 0; j < Mmz; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < Nmz; i++)
            F_X[j][i] = sin((float)i*j-i+123);

    for (i = 0; i < Nmz; i++)
        Zmz[i] = cos((float)2*i);
}

void Calc() {
    int h, k, j, i;
    float Rs = 0, a = 0, Tp = 0, Tv = 0;
    for(h = 0; h < Pk; h++)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < Lmz; k++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < Mmz; j++)
            {
                for(i = 0; i < Nmz; i++)
                {
                    a = (1.23 + US[h][k][j][i] / 0.321) * Rs * VS[h][k][j][i];
                    Tp = TS[h][k][j][i] * pow( 1000. / HS[h][k][j][i], 2./7. );
                    Tv = Tp * (1. + 0.6078 * QS[h][k][j][i]);
                    Q[h][k][j][i] = a - (0.5 * Tv + (1. - Zmz[k]) * 9.8 * F_X[j][i] / 0.321);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int h, k, j, i;
    clock_t timer;

    Init();

    timer = clock();
    Calc();
    printf("\ncalc time \t%f\n\n", (float)(clock() - timer));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too little data to draw any conclusions. Your test is a really simple one that only goes on for under three seconds. You are also using different compilers.

Comment: You are measuring speed of different implementations of functions `sin`, `cos`, `pow`. Barely has anything to do with compiler. Has nothing to do with OS.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  Using: `gcc -c -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`  the compiler output more than 40 warnings.

Comment: This is testing the math libraries, not the OS.

Comment: regarding: `a = (1.23 + US[h][k][j][i] / 0.321) * Rs * VS[h][k][j][i];` since `Rs` is initialized to 0 (should be initialized to 0.0f) the result of this calculation is always 0.

Comment: the use of this literal `0.321` (which is a `double` value) in a calculation that is (otherwise) all working with `float` values results in unnecessary conversions between `double` and `float`

Comment: While it might not show up in a test like this, keep in mind that clock() function in windows is entierly different than on linux. (windows clock function measures wall clock time, in linux it measures CPU time).

Comment: it is not a `apples` to `apples` comparison because they are different libraries

Comment: Looks like people have hard time noticing that only `Calc()` function is being measured... Anyway, try adding `-funroll-loops` to gcc's command-line. "fastest" on both compilers doesn't mean they enable the same optimizations. I don't know if vc unrolls loops by default, but gcc doesn't.

Comment: Does the code _function_ the exactly same?  Do the results of `Q[][]j][]` differ?  Which one is better?  IOWs, does the slower/ (or faster)  provide a _better_ answer?

Comment: You should probably show your full command line used for both programs. You should compile the Windows/MSVC program with `/arch:AVX` or `/arch:AVX2` and `/Oi /Oy /O2`. Its closer to the Linux/GCC command. The `/arch` option assumes you are using a modern iCore cpu.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-title the question so that it's about comparing two different compilers, rather than two different operating systems? If you want to compare operating systems, you need a benchmark that exercises OS functionality, not math and memory-juggling.

Comment: My purpose is to somehow make my Linux app faster to reach results comparable to Win, and currently I have no idea is it about compiler or runtimes or whatever or is it even possible.

Obtained calculations results are identical.

Build options for msvc:

/Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Ot /GL /D "WIN64" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_MBCS" /Gm- /EHsc /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope

gcc build command:

gcc -o  test test.c -O3 -lm

funroll-loops accelerates my app to 2600ms. The best Linux result 2550ms is obtained with -Ofast, that is unsafe and too slow anyway.

Comment: Compare the code. [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) exists for this reason.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?  For starters need to see the disassembly, need to see the C libraries (disassembled) and so on.  Benchmarks are BS in general, so you are probably just caught up in something that can be explained, but isnt some grand windows is faster than linux thing.  Trivial to make a benchmark that shows that as well as a benchmark that shows the opposite.

Answer (score -2):

I think your test is perfectly valid and the test results are accurate. You are not doing anything wrong. You are testing a complete tool chain, not just the OS. The main reason for the difference is the sad fact that Linux is not able to take advantage of hardware acceleration for the floating point operations. Or the graphics. There may be differences in the implementations of the trig functions, but I suspect that these differences are minimal. Most compiler supplied run times just use the original implementations first prescribed by the Fortran designers because there's no reason not to.